# android activities

Tags: android

i have 2 activities. 
1-Messaging
2-fileBrowser
from MESSAGING onButtonClick i call the FILEBROWSER activity. in the FILEBROWSER activity i take the path of the selected file and put it to a interface and then call the MESSAGING activity again like this :

```
  Intent i = new Intent(FileBrowser.this, Messaging.class);   
        i.putExtra(FriendInfo.P, path);  
        System.out.println("path at fb" + path);


        startActivity(i);
        this.finish();
```

now when i m returned back to the MESSAGING activity everything over here is null. all the variables and everything and if i call some other methods, the arguments i pass are also null. what do i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when first time you move Messaging to FileBrowser

```
instead of stariActivity() 

you can use StartActivityForResult()
```

method and at Activity FileBrowser just set result and put data in bundle then you can use this result in Messaging Activity's

```
onActivityResult().
```

Then your Messaging Activity's all variable remain same. No NULL value.

EDIT: In MessagingActivity

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Messaging.this, FileExplorer.class);
            intent.putExtra("Key", value);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
```

and also make this method

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //getting value from FileExplorer activity here
        }

 }
```

Comment: i dint understand the onActivityResult part. where do i put it?

Comment: one little question.this path string that i get i need to use it in a file like file f = new file(path); but this path that i got from the activity doesnt have quotes i want it to have quotes so that i could pass it to the file. how can i achieve that?

Comment: pass the path as a string format in intent from activity FileExplorer to Messagging Acitivty.

Comment: soryy im a noob. i just did :)

Comment: public void onFileClick(Option o)
    {
     String path = o.getPath();
 
     String username = new String();
     
  System.out.println("path at fb" + path);


 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString("pathParameter", path);
  Intent mIntent = new Intent();
  mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
  setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
  finish();


    }
   this is how i do it. it says "o" isnt a file. so i cant get the absolute path :(

Comment: i did that. i get the path. now in a sendFile activity i pass that same path. so that path isnt enclosed in quotes, its without the quotes like this (/sdcard/file.txt/). it should be enclosed in quotes to be passed to the sendFile method. i.e   File  f = new File(path);

Comment: in a senFileactivity when you get path from intent as a STRING then after use that string in file parameter like, File f=new File(filepath); , the problem is because your file path is not in string format. :-)

Comment: it is in string format :S like this : String path = o.getPath();

Comment: then it should work. ok try this File f=new File("+filepath+");

Comment: thank you so much. it worked without the plus signs. i have put 2 more questions that no one is responding to. can u check them out? also related to android. and how do i favourite u?

Comment: here is one, the other one is actually solved :)      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335317/file-transfer-in-android

Comment: yes it uses tcp/ip. (for some reason i cant put comments on that question :S )

Answer (score 1):

Try to start your Intent with `StartActivityForResult(Intent intent)`

Comment: where exactly? when im calling FILEBROWSER from MESSAGING? or when m calling MESSAGING again?