# FILE TRANSFER in android

Tags: android

this is regarding android instant messenger. im trying to send a file, and this is how i send it :

```
@Override
public boolean sendFile(String path,String ip, int port) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


try {

String[] str = ip.split("\\.");

byte[] IP = new byte[str.length];

for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    IP[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str[i]);


}
Socket socket = getSocket(InetAddress.getByAddress(IP), port);
if (socket == null) {
    Log.i("SO sendFILE","null");

    return false;
}

Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-1");
File  f = new File(path);


BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );

FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(f);
Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-2");




byte [] buffer  = new byte [1024];
    int bytesRead =0;
    while ((bytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        System.out.println("SO sendFile" + bytesRead);
    }
out.flush();
out.close();
fileIn.close();
Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-3");






    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;           
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //  Toast.makeText(this, "Lvbvhhging...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return true;        
}
```

this is how i receive connection and seperate text from file (i concatenate "text" to the output stream for the text)

```
public ReceiveConnection(Socket socket) 
        {
            this.clientSocket = socket;
            this.fileSocket=socket;
            SocketOperator.this.sockets.put(socket.getInetAddress(), socket);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
             try {
    //          PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                // PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                               new InputStreamReader(
                                        clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                     InputStream is=clientSocket.getInputStream();




                    String inputLine;
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)                  {



                         if (inputLine.contains("Text") == true)
                         {


                            appManager.messageReceived(inputLine);  
                    Log.i("SocketOP","text");}

                         else  if 
                        (inputLine.contains("Text") == false)
                        {

                            Log.i("SocketOP","filee");
                             appManager.fileReceived(is);

                         }



                    else{

                         clientSocket.shutdownInput();
                         clientSocket.shutdownOutput();
                         clientSocket.close();

                         fileSocket.shutdownInput();
                         fileSocket.shutdownOutput();
                         fileSocket.close();
                         SocketOperator.this.sockets.remove(clientSocket.getInetAddress());
                         SocketOperator.this.sockets.remove(fileSocket.getInetAddress());

                         Log.i("SocketOP", "CLOSING CONNECTION");
                     }                       
            }       

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("ReceiveConnection.run: when receiving connection ","");
        }           
        }   
    }
```

and this is how i finally receive the file in a service called imService :

```
public void fileReceived(InputStream is)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Log.i("IMSERVICE", "FILERECCC-1");


    if (is!= null) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/chats/ffffff.txt");
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            byte[] aByte = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            System.out.println("imService fileReceive" + bytesRead);

            while ((bytesRead = is.read(aByte)) != -1) {
                bos.write(aByte, 0, bytesRead);
                System.out.println("imService fileReceive" + bytesRead);

            }
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
            Log.i("IMSERVICE", "FILERECCC-2");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Do exception handling
        }
    }
```

right where i receive the file connection and forward the inputstream IS to the file receive method, i see that its getting the bytes but once filereceived is called it isnt receving any bytes.

it uses tcp/ip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, try it on your method

```
public void fileReceived(InputStream is)
 throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
  {
    string result; 
   FileOutputStream fos = null;        
    fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/chats/ffffff.txt"); 

   Log.i("IMSERVICE", "FILERECCC-1");       
 if (is!= null) 
{  

 // result = convertStreamToString(is);              
 // result = result.replace("\n", ""); 
 // Log.e("InputStream output",result);


  //IOUtils.copy(is,fos);

   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
     int length;     
   while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
             {     
       fos.write(buffer, 0, length);     
   }      
      // Close the streams     
       fos.flush();     
       fos.close();     
        is.close();     


}     

} 

  /*    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) 
  throws Exception 
   {      
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();     
     String line = null;     
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
              {         
             sb.append(line + "\n");     
              }     
            is.close();     
       return sb.toString(); 
       } 
   */
```

EDIT: make other stuff in fileReceived method as comment.. just paste my suggested code.

EDIT: its a IOUtils from apache use it..

Comment: thank you :) and where do i write the file? i hope this would work.

Comment: thank you so much. you are the best :) really. one quick question, how do i use IOUtils? :S

Comment: make a class IOUils? and then import it?

Comment: its still not writing it to the file..its showing the right output in the log but the created file size is still 0 bytes...omg..:'(

Comment: if i do int a = is.read() and log it, it says is = -1 .. thats why it isnt going into the while loop in the first place..

Comment: just carefully show my edited code use it. and let me know what happen. be aware I commeted some lines and also on function convertstring you also remove it.

Comment: its created an empty file of the same size as of the source file.i mean i sent a file of 10 kb and it received it and created a file of 10 kb but its empty.

Comment: how can you said the file is empty? how can you check the file?

Comment: no no its not empty that was a mistake..i get the file from the emulator and save it to the pc..and then i can open it.

Comment: make some time delay after writting the file, if size of files are same then file must writted completely, look that file after some time, you get whole data in it..

Comment: man its working..thank you so much..omg i cant believe it...thanks alottttttttt

Comment: awww im so sorry i dont have that sort of reputation. other wise i would definitely have voted u.

Comment: your most welcome...thank you so much again...m totaly obliged..thank you thank you

Comment: hi, could you please tell me how do i send the filename along with the stream and then get that filename?

Comment: or do i put a new question for this if u want :)

Comment: please put a new question on SO. Thanks